# Where can I find info about OS/A WASP operating system for Soviet BK series computers?

Tags: electronika-bk

OS/A WASP was allegedly developed by Kamnev, one of the creators of ANDOS and maybe others, but any information about this operating system is scarce. I heard rumors that it had windowing interface "like in Windows".

Is there a way to find any info about it online?

**UPDATE**

I found a file by AltPro firm where they refer to 3(!) different windowing systems for BK: LIS-WINDOWS, OS/A WASP and AltPro Windows. It is unclear if they are completely different or different versions of one development. The text says, OS/A WASP includes "additional features", but has "different ideology, that differs not necessarily in the bad direction". Regarding OS/A WASP the text says it supports parallel processes and batch files, it also allows to switch between ANDOS and MKDOS operating systems without rebooting.

The disk image (BKMANIA972) also includes the demo version of AltPro Windows, although I was unsuccessful to make it work on an emulator.

Here is a screenshot of the claims made:
[image]

Particularly, it says it would work under all the BK series computers with AltPro disk controllers. It claims AltPro Windows as of the moment supports only ANDOS operating system. It also says the AltPro Windows system loads before an operating system, such as ANDOS.

Splash screen of the demo version:

[image]

The screen suggests pressing a key to chose a drive letter. After pressing any key though the program exits to the file manager.

I also was able to find an HDD image which should include OS/A WASP but the image is intended for a real BK computer with flash drive and I was not able to mount it under an emulator: http://files.pk-fpga.ru/storage/bk-software/hdd_images/1Gb_CF_dump_2022_11_14.rar

**UPDATE2**

Lis corp. seems to be a pseudonym of A.V. Grishin.

Comment: It may be helpful to add some/all sources you have (so far) to support its existence in general.

Comment: @Raffzahn This user also asks about it, says he only has a video about it: http://bk10.pdp-11.ru/forum/?id=1529&page=22

Comment: @Raffzahn this list of operating systems for BK also mentions it, says it was not a stand-alone OS but the one booting from inside MKDOS. https://zx-pk.ru/content/134-Obzor-kompiuterov-Elektronika-BK

Comment: @Raffzahn here someone posted a HDD image with it but it is not available now: https://web.archive.org/web/20230402085459/http://forum.pk-fpga.ru/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=1555

Comment: Please edit the question to add those sources. Comments may get deleted.

Comment: Again: Please,pretty please, help to improve the site and add those links to your question and make it worth for later usage. All information needs to be provided within the question text. Comments are for others to comment on that question.

Answer (score 1):

A HD controller for the BK series I used to have was "optimized" by omitting port inverters. Therefore, every byte of data on the physical disk images needed "XOR 0xFF" to arrive at its actual value to be used in an emulator.

Comment: Tis should be a comment. I have never heard about need to invert data for a BK disk, the FAT12 floppies from MS-DOS were read by ANDOS just well.

Comment: This does not seem to address the question, which was about the OS/A WASP operating system.

Comment: Agreed, not exactly a spot on answer,but still illustrating an important point about  Sowjet computers of that time: Due a very limited resource of official products an almost innumerable number of  individual products were made - software and hardware.

Comment: @Anixx Floppies are different. The low-level interface to a floppy drive was implemented by an OEM extension, so it was done faithfully.

Comment: @another-dave Given that the question mentions "I also was able to find an HDD image which should include OS/A WASP but the image is intended for a real BK computer with flash drive", please tell me what part of the question doesn't the answer address? The implied answer is "On the HDD image that you have, if you look at it properly".

Comment: LOL Why one should think that this image is not mountable because it is for that specific kind of disc controller of yours that no-one ever heard of? To attach a flash drive to a BK computer they use very advanced controllers that had no such problems as inverted data (this was achieved in the 2000s already, not in the 1990s).

Comment: @Raffzahn A handmade HDD interface board that I had was mounted inside the FDD extension box. It had to have a bare minimum of components to fit, so the inverters were omitted. The driver must have taken care to issue inverted IDE commands and to invert the response codes, but the data was sent as is for speed. As one of the first designers had used this convention, and his design got popular, other designers would have followed suit for compatibility.

Comment: @Anixx HDD images found on the net are from the pre-flash era. I know what I'm talking about because I had connected a CompactFlash card to a BK. The disk controller was not of my design, it was bought back in the 90s.

Comment: This image is intended for controller SMK-512. It does not have any such quirck of data inversion. Under emulator I also used the SMK-512 option.

Comment: @Anixx Then it must have some other quirk if the image is not readily acceptable by the software emulator. Perhaps the first few blocks may have to be omitted, or pairs of bytes flipped, or something else of that sort.  As far as the specific piece of hardware you're dealing with is not that old, another forum may be more appropriate, https://misterfpga.org/viewtopic.php?t=3963 or nearby.

Comment: I do not have any retrohardware.

Comment: @LeoB.  OK, I guess, but the connection with the question (especially the title line of the question) was far from obvious to me.  Maybe edit to make the implicit explicit?